# How to point the database source to an IP instead of localhost on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish-4

I am configuring my glassfish server so that a java web application fetches data from an **IP** (162.17.17.53) instead of **localhost**. When I try **PING** button on the JDBC Resiurce Pool, I get the below error:

**Access denied for user 'user'@'162.17.17.54' (using password: YES) Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.**

NB: The machine I am doing the configurations on has the IP 162.17.17.54. Please assist

Comment: Can you post any related error from the server.log?

Comment: ` RAR5110 : Error creating managed Connection with user and password : {0}
`